# Problem with Azure Machine learning and batch endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, automl

I created a model with automl, obviously I used the best model and I created a batch endpoint. With Azure Data factory I'm calling the batch endpoint and I don't know why but when the job starts it fails immediately with this error:

Unable to get image details : Image mcr.microsoft.com/mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/azureml-automl:141 for environment batch-inference-ncd-env does not exist in registry..

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gNap.png)

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6z9m.png)

It could run, or at least it has to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue based on the scenario.
[image]

It seems like the image URL is incorrect: `mcr.microsoft.com/mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/azureml-automl:141`. There is a duplicate `mcr.microsoft.com` in the URL.
[image]

To resolve this issue, you should update the image URL in your batch endpoint configuration to the correct one.
The correct image URL should look like this:

`mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/azureml-automl:141`.
[image]

update the endpoint with new deployment configuration and the endpoint should work fine.
[image]

Comment: Where do I find the configuration for batch endpoint? It's everything autogenerated.

Comment: Same here - have the exact same issue and would love to know how to get around the issue for a deployment to an endpoint via the Azure UI.

Comment: I raised a support ticket with Microsoft and, after working with them during this week, they have now confirmed it is a bug and they are working on a fix as a priority (no ETA yet).